# How to pass data parameter to ajax action function handler

Tags: ajax

I have the following js to process an ajax request:

```
$('#someelement').click(function() {

        var cokeValue = 'coke';

        var data = {
            action: 'load_post',
            another_par: someVar
        };

        jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
  });
```

And this is my ajax handler function (hopefully my terminology is correct):

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_coke', 'get_coke_ajax');
function get_coke_ajax() {

   // need to get another_par in here !!!!!!!

   die();
}
```

As you can see, the action is `load_post` which is fine, but I need to pass the `another_par` parameter to my ajax function so that I can assign its value to a variable and use it for my purposes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you use [`jQuery.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), the `data` is sent as regular `$_POST` arguments.

So this JavaScript …

```
var data = {
    action: 'load_post',
    foo:    'bar'
};
```

… is available in your callback function per:

```
$action = $_POST['action'];
$foo    = $_POST['foo']; // bar
```

And when you are using `jQuery.get()`, the data is in `$_GET`. You can also use `$_REQUEST` which returns both, `GET` and `POST` data (and `COOKIE`). But you should always ask for the specific resource to avoid injection from sources you didn’t expect, like a cookie.

Comment: Sorry, my WordPress escapes the input, when it is json_encoded. Some slashes are added infront of " characters.

https://wpartisan.me/tutorials/wordpress-auto-adds-slashes-post-get-request-cookie