# post value to function with Ajax and jQuery

Tags: functions, filters, ajax, jquery, actions

This is how you would create a custom smart tag in wp forms:

```
function ea_custom_smart_tags( $content, $tag ) {
    if( 'my_smart_tag' == $tag ) {
        $value = 'Testing 1 2 3';
        $content = str_replace( '{' . $tag . '}', $value, $content );
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'wpforms_smart_tag_process', 'ea_custom_smart_tags', 10, 2 );
```

I want to post a value via ajax instead of hard coding it.

My `jQuery/ajax`:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/mywebsite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: {
        action: 'my_action',
        theTotal: newTotal
    },
}).success(function (result) {
    alert(result);
});
```

My `functions.php`:

```
function my_action_callback($content, $tag){


if ( 'total' === $tag ) {

 $total = $_POST['theTotal'];

 $content = str_replace( '{total}', $total, $content );

}

return $content;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_filter( 'wpforms_smart_tag_process', 'my_action_callback', 10, 2 );
```

This is however giving me an error:

> Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
>   my_action_callback(), 1 passed in and exactly 2 expected

Comment: I see you used the old legacy Admin AJAX handler. Is there a reason you went for this rather than the simpler/modern REST API to handle your JS requests?

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite self-explanatory. Your last lines are:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_filter( 'wpforms_smart_tag_process', 'my_action_callback', 10, 2 );
```

The action is calling the same function as the filter. But the filter passes two variables and the action only one. The function itself expects two variables:

```
function my_action_callback($content, $tag)
```

So if you call the function through the (ajax) action, you get this error. You'll have to pass `$tag` through your ajax call as well. Otherwise `my_action_callback` wouldn't do anything anyway, because it demands `$tag` to be `'total'`. Or you could ditch `$tag` as a variable, since it is not doing a lot anyway.

Update: you can also make `PHP` be more forgiving by adding defaults in the function call:

```
my_action_callback($content='', $tag='')
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to send the tag in ajax but clearly I am not doing it correctly as I am still getting the same error. `data: {
        action: 'my_action',
        content: newTotal, 
        tag: 'score'
    },`

Comment: You can't send arguments to the `wp_ajax_` callback function with AJAX. You will need a separate function just for the AJAX callback that calls `my_action_callback()` with the arguments.

Comment: ay, I am getting lost now..

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134413/how-to-pass-data-parameter-to-ajax-action-function-handler

Comment: @Iggy'sPop Did you add `,10,2` to the `add_action`?

Comment: @cjbj, I did but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I added an update to the answer that might take away the error, but may not solve the passing problem

Comment: @cjbj, thank you yes, that takes away the error but the actual value is not returned on the frontend.

Comment: the old Admin AJAX doesn't pass things via function parameters, that's not how that API works

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes, but if you want to use the same function for both, you'll have to match them to prevent the error, and then inside the function retrieve the `$_POST` parameters in case of an ajax call.

Comment: You'd still need to retrieve the content from somewhere, the javascript side would need to be modified too